# run 'while-loop' for many times

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I have to generate random variables in R until the sum of the variables exceed 2 , and investigate the number of random variables generated which I called it "n" . I have done this part *using while(sum>2) , my question now is how to run this for many times to get a mean of "n" ? Is it correct to use a "for" loop ? Thanks a lot !
Here is my code now :`

```
n=0
s=0
while(s>2){
n=n+1
rv=runif(n,0,1)
s=s+sum(rv)}
print(n)
```

how can I run it for many times to get mean of "n" ?

`

Answer (score 2):

To make this a little more efficient I would suggest you only call `runif()` once and populate a matrix where each column has enough samples that will guarantee that the sum exceeds 2. We can then find the point at which we have enough samples and calculate the mean.

**Code**

```
mean(apply(matrix(runif(1e6), nrow = 20), 2, function(x){
  sum(cumsum(x) < 2)
}))

# 3.67506
```

Comment: @himalaya you're welcome, if you want you can choose the most helpful answer and accept it by clicking on the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your condition should be `s < 2` in `while` loop. You can write it in the function.

```
run_sim <- function() {
  n=0
  s=0
  while(s<2){
    n=n+1
    rv=runif(n,0,1)
    s=s+sum(rv)
  }
  return(n)
}
```

and use `replicate` to repeat the process `n` times and take the `mean`.

```
mean(replicate(100, run_sim()))
#[1] 2.96
```